# Cómo migrar SecurityConfig.xml a Java

Tags: spring, ldap

Buenas,

He tratado de migrar el siguiente segmento de código XML dentro de una aplicación Spring MVC a Java, pero no he logrado como hacerlo, ¿me podrían ayudar?

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=People"
                           group-search-base="ou=Roles"
                           group-search-filter="uniqueMember={0}"
                           server-ref="ldapServer"
                           user-context-mapper-ref="contextMapper"
                                           /> 
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server id="ldapServer" 
              url="ldap://192.168.40.105:10389/dc=stl,dc=com" 
              manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system"
              manager-password="secret"  />     

<bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
      <constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
      <constructor-arg value="ou=Roles"/>
      <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/>
      <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
      <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Cualquier guía o link se los agradecería.

Answer (score 1):

A continuación hay una clase de configuración Java que hace el mismo comportamiento que el xml que has puesto en la pregunta (salvo error u omisión :). Se incluye tambien alguna configuración extra de la seguridad, que no aparecia en el xml los métodos configure que en tu caso puede que ya los tengas en otra configuración.

Principalment se trata de construir el AuthenticatioManager que se obtiene con la anotación @Autowired en el método configureGlobal. Obteniento el AuthentitacionManagerBuilder se acede através del método ldapAuthenticacion() al LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer que da acceso a la configuración de LDAP. Aquí tienes el JavaDoc del LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer con las opciones que se pueden configurar. 
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.ldapAuthentication()
                            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                            .groupSearchBase("ou=Roles")
                            .groupSearchFilter("uniqueMember={0}")
                            .contextSource(ldapContextSource())
                     .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator());
      }


      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http = http.csrf().disable()
               .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutok").and()
               .httpBasic().and()
               .exceptionHandling().and()
               .headers().disable();

      }

      @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
      }

      @Bean
      protected DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource ldapContextSource() {
          final DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://192.168.40.105:10389/dc=stl,dc=com");

          contextSource.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
          contextSource.setPassword("secret");
          contextSource.setReferral("follow");

          return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    protected LdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator() {
        final ContextSource contextSource = ldapContextSource();

        DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource,"ou=Roles");
        ldapAuthoritiesPopulator.setGroupRoleAttribute("cn");
        ldapAuthoritiesPopulator.setGroupSearchFilter("uniqueMember={0}");
        ldapAuthoritiesPopulator.setRolePrefix("ROLE_");
        ldapAuthoritiesPopulator.setConvertToUpperCase(true);

        return ldapAuthoritiesPopulator;
    }
}
```